# remote true on links been processed as html instead of js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku, remote-server

Links with **remote=true** in my rails application on heroku are not been processed correctly in heroku, they are supposed to be processed as `JS`, rather, they are been processed as `HTML` on the **heroku server**.

**log from the heroku server**

[image: log from heroku server]

meanwhile, when same application is been ran locally, these links are been processed correctly (proccessed as `JS`).

**logs from my local server**

[image: log from local server]

Below is the code snippet carry those links in my rails `Rails 5.0.0.1`
 application

```
<div id = "navs" class="admin-nav">
  <ul class="na">
       <li class = "adminli" id = "dash">
            <%= image_tag('navs/course.svg', class: 'icon icon-img')%>
            <%= link_to "Dashboard", admin_dashboard_path, remote:true %>
       </li>
       <li class = "adminli" id = "lect">
            <%= image_tag('navs/lecturer.svg', class: 'icon icon-img')%>
            <%= link_to "Lecturer", admin_lecturer_path, remote:true %>
      </li>
      <li class = "adminli" id = "stud">
            <%= image_tag('navs/student.svg', class: 'icon icon-img')%>
            <%= link_to "Student", admin_student_path, remote:true %>
      </li>
      <li class = "adminli" id = "cos">
             <%= image_tag('navs/course.svg', class: 'icon icon-img')%>
             <%= link_to "Courses", admin_course_path, remote:true %>
      </li>
      <li class = "adminli" id = "new">
              <%= image_tag('navs/news.svg', class: 'icon icon-img')%>
               <%= link_to "News", admin_news_path, remote:true %>
       </li>
       <li class = "adminli" id = "session_act">
               <%= image_tag('navs/news.svg', class: 'icon icon-img')%>
               <%= link_to "Session Activities", "admin_session_activities_path", remote:true %>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

The above links can be found when logged in as an admin in [my rails application](https://elect1.herokuapp.com).

**admin login details for the application**

username : samuel

password : samuel

Comment: can you check heroku log so that you will get exact errror what error is as when you click on last side bar.

Comment: Thanks man have checked it and it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking lots of error on the console see below image

[image]

At first, you have to solve the error then try or ask the forum.

`remote: true` is related with `JS` if you have `JS` error then not to work that's why you need to solve all `console` error.

Thanks